# Does Visual Studio 2017 use the Language Server Protocol?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, languageservice, language-server-protocol

[Language Server Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) was created for VS-Code (not the Visual Studio IDE).
It is a rather sensible idea about providing language services like various linting and code-completion (intillisense).
It is by no means the first-time that idea has been had,
but it has seen rather rapid and wide-scale support from a large number of languages.

Is it used by Visual Studio 2017?
I can't seem to find the creating extensions docs for 2017.
eg the [2015 docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885118.aspx).

If not, is there an official language server plugin that allows LSP resources to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (Feb 2019):** support for the Language Server Protocol is now [built in to Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2017).

---

This question was not able to answer, as only Microsoft holds the key. But luckily after half a year, Microsoft did announce the fact that Visual Studio would support LSP,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/11/21/announcing-language-server-protocol-preview-release/

The extension only works for Visual Studio Preview builds right now, and also lacks many important features,

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsext.LanguageServerClientPreview

We can see that there is still a long way to go.